# How do you change the content div based on the navigation hover

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic, navigation

I want to display my contact form when the user hovers over my navigation menu "contact" list item using css.

So I want to have a solution that explains how I can use css to hover over "A" (menu item) to display the content corresponding to "A" (content) or if you hover over B it displays B and so on.

Comment: sounds like a test question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The only problem I see with doing this, is that if the user is on a mobile device, you will have to code for a mobile device. The best solution is to create a div with the information in it, and the display set to none. Place a hover that changes the display to block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is great tutorial that i used for my website:

http://codeissue.com/articles/a04e0d17a60fad8/simple-html-drop-down-hover-menu-using-just-css-no-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple solution based on pure CSS (no javascripting, so it will work even if javascript is disabled on client's computer):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="itemHeader">A</div>
</body>
```

**CSS3**

```
div.itemHeader {cursor:pointer;}

div.itemHeader:after {
    content: "Blah-Blah-Blah";
    color: #909090;
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
}

div.itemHeader:hover:after{opacity:1;}
```

link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/